# Validate euro string currency

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate the user input in a text field is a valid amount in euro.

Examples:

```
100,00 //valid
100,123123 //valid
100.000,21 //valid
100000 //valid

10.00.00 //invalid
100,000,000 //invalid
```

Decimals separated with a comma, optional dot for the integers.

I managed to come close to what I want with this

```
static validateEuro = value => {
  const pattern = /^\d+(?:,?\d+)$/;
  return pattern.test(`${value}`);
}
```

**But it fails to validate in case of correctly placed dots, e.g. ** `100.000.000`

Tests:

```js
  it('Values without comma or dot are valid integers', () => {
    expect(AmountInput.validateEuro('100')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(AmountInput.validateEuro(1000)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Values with a single comma are valid', () => {
    expect(AmountInput.validateEuro('100,00')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(AmountInput.validateEuro('100,131')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Values with more than a comma are invalid', () => {
    expect(AmountInput.validateEuro('100,000,000')).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('Values with wrong placed dots should be invalid', () => {
    expect(AmountInput.validateEuro('10.00.00')).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('Values with correct placed dots should be valid', () => {
    expect(AmountInput.validateEuro('100.000.000')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Values with characters should be invalid', () => {
    expect(AmountInput.validateEuro('asda10')).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You're of course free to name your functions whatever you like, but euro isn't a format. Even within the Eurozone not all countries use your allowed formats. For example the Republic of Ireland uses a comma as a thousand separator and France uses a (non-breaking) space.

Just for your information. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the [following regex:](https://regex101.com/r/4eeoZy/1)

```
^(\d+|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*)(,\d+)?$
```

Let's decipher that:

```
^                              $  # match complete line
 (\d+|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*)          # match the part before the comma
     |                            # match either:
  \d+                             # a sequence of digits
      \d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*           # or this, which is:
      \d{1,3}                     # up to three digits, followed by
             (\.\d{3})*           # a dot, and three digits, 0 or more times
                        (,\d+)?   # match the part after the comma, if it exists 
                         ,\d+     # a comma, followed by at least one digit
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RegEx [`^(\d)+(,\d+)?$|^(\d{3}\.?)+(,\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/pYpgjJ/1/)

In this RegEx, I separated the case where the number is written with or without `dots`.

`^(\d)+(,\d+)?$` matches the numbers without dots

- `(\d)+` matches a digit at least once
- `(,\d+)?` matches `,[at least one digit]` one or zero times

`^(\d{3}\.?)+(,\d+)?$` matches the numbers with dots

- `(\d{3}\.?)+` matches the sequence `[digit][digit][digit].?` at least once
- `(,\d+)?` matches `,[at least one digit]` one or zero times

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pYpgjJ/1/)**

Comment: Fails for (probably invalid) `100.000000.000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex:

```
function validate(value) {
var regex = /^[1-9]\d*(((.\d{3}){1})?(\,\d{0,2})?)$/;

if (regex.test(value))
{
    var twoDecimalPlaces = /\,\d{2}$/g;
    var oneDecimalPlace = /\,\d{1}$/g;
    var noDecimalPlacesWithDecimal = /\,\d{0}$/g;

    if(value.match(twoDecimalPlaces ))
    {
        return value;
    }
    if(value.match(noDecimalPlacesWithDecimal))
    {
        return value+'00';
    }
    if(value.match(oneDecimalPlace ))
    {
        return value+'0';
    }
    return value+",00";
}
return null;
};
```